# Pass data from Flask into a seperate Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm running a flask application where I get information from a user's uploaded CSV and I'm trying to take that data and pass it into a separate javascript file I have.

@app.route('/') is the route that gets the users csv file and sends it to the upload,html

***main.py***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
        return render_template('upload.html', shape=df.shape)
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route("/graph")
def graph():
    return render_template("graph.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This javascript builds a sankey graph, it's connected to a css that formats it.

***function.js***

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                var index = point.index + 1,
                    from = point.from,
                    to = point.to,
                    weight = point.weight;
                return index + '. ' + from + ' to ' + to + ', ' + weight + '.';
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 5],
            ['Brazil', 'France', 1],
            ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1],
            ['Brazil', 'England', 1],
            ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['Canada', 'France', 5],
            ['Canada', 'England', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'France', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'Spain', 5],
            ['Mexico', 'England', 1],
            ['USA', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['USA', 'France', 1],
            ['USA', 'Spain', 1],
            ['USA', 'England', 5],
            ['Portugal', 'Angola', 2],
            ['Portugal', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['Portugal', 'Morocco', 1],
            ['Portugal', 'South Africa', 3],
            ['France', 'Angola', 1],
            ['France', 'Senegal', 3],
            ['France', 'Mali', 3],
            ['France', 'Morocco', 3],
            ['France', 'South Africa', 1],
            ['Spain', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['Spain', 'Morocco', 3],
            ['Spain', 'South Africa', 1],
            ['England', 'Angola', 1],
            ['England', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['England', 'Morocco', 2],
            ['England', 'South Africa', 7],
            ['South Africa', 'China', 5],
            ['South Africa', 'India', 1],
            ['South Africa', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Angola', 'China', 5],
            ['Angola', 'India', 1],
            ['Angola', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Senegal', 'China', 5],
            ['Senegal', 'India', 1],
            ['Senegal', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Mali', 'China', 5],
            ['Mali', 'India', 1],
            ['Mali', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Morocco', 'China', 5],
            ['Morocco', 'India', 1],
            ['Morocco', 'Japan', 3]
        ],
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series'
    }]

});
```

This is the html file that currently displays the shape variable from main.py

***upload.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
Shape is: {{ shape }}
</body>
</html>
```

***graph.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container"></div>
        <p class="highcharts-description">
            Sankey charts are used to visualize data flow and volume
            between nodes. The wider lines indicate larger volumes.
        </p>
    </figure>

  </body>

  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/template.css') }}">
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='function.js') }}"></script>  

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The way I solved this was by simply embedding the javascript into the html, I couldn't find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and arrived at here, for now the answer I found is to convert csv file to json (json.dump) and send it to independent JS file in static folder. This article gives full explanation: https://towardsdatascience.com/combining-python-and-d3-js-to-create-dynamic-visualization-applications-73c87a494396

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.